# Send mail as from my personal gmail account

Tags: mail, gmail

Today I have tried `mail` utility from my ubuntu system. Now in `mail` command, I could not find an utility to send mail from my gmail account. In fact, it sends from some `adhikarisubir@ubutu` (adhikarisubir is my login name). So wondering is it possible to send mails from my gmail account?
Also, I noticed simple mails generated from sendmail goes to junk folders in gmail; In fact rediff does not allow to accept these mails. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

To send mail from your gmail account in Ubuntu system test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall msmtp-mta heirloom-mailx
apt-get clean
exit
nano ~/.mailrc
```

In the open file, paste these lines:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set message-sendmail-extra-arguments="-a gmail"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue run:

```
nano ~/.msmtprc
```

In the open file, paste these lines:

```
#Gmail account
defaults
logfile ~/msmtp.log

account gmail
auth on
host smtp.gmail.com
from adhikarisubir@gmail.com
auth on
tls on
tls_trust_file /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Equifax_Secure_CA.crt
user adhikarisubir@gmail.com
password your_gmail_password
port 587

account default : gmail
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
chmod 600 .msmtprc
```

You can send email from the command line like this:

```
mail -s "subject" address@mail.com
```

The cursor will go to a blank line.

Enter your email message.

When you're done, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to a blank line

And then hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to end and sent your message.